# Using pre compiled templates with Ember

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, handlebars.js

I have precompiled my Ember templates and included them into my index.html as a js file.

MY question is - How do I now display the pre compiled templates in my Ember App?

The templates work find when inline on the html page, but not when included as an import.

Many thanks

C

Comment: Please provide some code/directory structure

Comment: You don't have to do anything different client side, are you sure they're being inject in the page after you're Ember include.

Comment: Ensure that you're injecting them properly: `Ember.TEMPLATES["template/name"] = ...`